# Open and Populate a DataGridView in Visual Studio

Tags: datagridview

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Create ADO.NET objects.
Private myConn As SqlConnection
Private myCmd As SqlCommand
Private myReader As SqlDataReader
Private results As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Create a Connection object.
    myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAURENCE-NB\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=insourcenet;Integrated Security=True")

    'Open the connection.
    myConn.Open()

    'Create a Command object.
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from custinfo" '(or any other info I may select)


    'The line below will populate the DataGrid but with all info and I want the ability to select the info to fill from the 'SELECT' command above.
    'My datagrid name is DataDridView1
    CustinfoTableAdapter.Fill(InsourcenetDataSet.custinfo)


   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Private Sub upload_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sqlcn As New SqlConnection("server=laurence-nb\sqlexpress;database=insourcenet;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim sadapt As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from custinfo", sqlcn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        sadapt.Fill(ds, "custinfo")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("custinfo")
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Solution as found is above